# Forwarding reference for struct as a parameter in a function template with SFINAE

Tags: c++, function, templates, sfinae, enable-if

I wonder why this code does not compile:

```
struct S{ int m; };

template<class T, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, S>>>
T& operator+=(T&& arg0, int arg1)
{
    arg0.m += arg1;
    return arg0;
}

int main()
{   
    S val0{ 0 }; int val1{ 1 };
    val0 += val1;

    return 0;
}
```

But it does compile either when SFINAE removed or when basic integer is used instead of a struct (with an appropriate template code change).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that for forwarding references, since `val0` is an lvalue, `T` gets deduced as a `S&`, not a `S`.  That causes `std::is_same_v<T, S>` to fail as a `S` is not the same as a `S&`.  To fix this you can use `std::decay_t` to remove the reference like

```
template<class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, S>, int> = 0>
T& operator+=(T&& arg0, int arg1)
{
    arg0.m += arg1;
    return arg0;
}
```

I also adjusted the template to use a defaulted non-type parameter instead of defaulted type parameter.  Doing it this way allows you to overload the function easier as default type arguments are not part of the function signature unlike default values.

Comment: @oleksijp I'd have to see the code you are using in order to tell you.  If you changed `T&&` to `int&&` then I can tell you, you no longer have a forwarding reference, but an rvalue reference.

Comment: I think maybe it's because there is a non-template overload for ints :D

Comment: @oleksijp Ah yes, `int& operator +=(int, int)` is already defined by the compiler.